# Segmentation fault in my derived type code

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran

I can't wrap my head around what's wrong with my Fortran code. It compiles but reliably dies during execution (segmentation fault).

The main program instantiates my class `cell_autom` as `ma`. It also instantiates my class `random_pathfinder` as `pf` and passes my `ma` instance as an argument to its constructor:

```
use ClassCellularAutomata
use ClassRule
use ClassRandomPathfinder
implicit none

class(random_pathfinder), allocatable :: pf
class(cell_autom), allocatable :: ma
integer, parameter :: width = 30
integer, parameter :: T_steps = 3
integer, parameter :: step_dist = 4
double precision, parameter :: goal_score = 0.90

allocate(ma, source = moore_autom(width, width, T_steps))
call ma%rule%generate_random()
call ma%random_seed_field()

allocate(pf, source = random_pathfinder(ma, step_dist, goal_score))
call pf%run_pathfinder()
```

Now, the segmentation fault occurs during the construction of `pf`, respectively in the `setup` constructor statement `allocate(inst%autom, source = autom)`:

```
module ClassRandomPathfinder
use ClassCellularAutomata
use ClassRule
implicit none

type random_pathfinder
    class(cell_autom), allocatable :: autom
    type(rule) :: goal_rule
    integer :: step_dist
    logical, allocatable :: goal_pattern(:,:)
    logical, allocatable :: steps_done(:)
    double precision :: current_score, goal_score
    integer(kind=4) :: path_length

    contains

    procedure, pass(this) :: run_pathfinder

end type

interface random_pathfinder
    procedure setup
end interface

contains

function setup(autom, step_dist, goal_score) result(inst)
    implicit none
    class(random_pathfinder), allocatable :: inst
    class(cell_autom) :: autom
    integer, intent(in) :: step_dist
    double precision, intent(in) :: goal_score
    integer :: i

    ! Set init values
    allocate(inst%autom, source = autom)
    inst%step_dist = step_dist
    inst%goal_score = goal_score

    ! Setup the random pathfinder
    ! Init goal rule
    inst%goal_rule = inst%autom%rule

    ! Run it once to get the goal pattern
    call inst%autom%run()
    inst%goal_pattern = inst%autom%get_last_pattern()

    ! Reset the automaton
    call inst%autom%reset_to_last_start()

    ! change the rule
    do i = 1, inst%step_dist
        call inst%autom%rule%flip_random_rule_entry()
    end do

end function setup
```

My first idea was to blame the allocation statement itself or my `autom` or `cell_autom` definition. But after I commented out the line (and others), the segmentation fault just occured in the next line with an `inst%` assignment. So I guess the problem lies with my `random_pathfinder` class or its constructor.

I am quite new to Fortran's oop and have no idea what's going wrong. Maybe one of you sees one or several obvious mistakes.

I am using f08 with the gfortran compiler. Another problem is that gdb doesn't stop at my geany breakpoints in oop programs (yes I used the -g flag).

To make it complete, here is my `cell_autom` type definition:

```
type cell_autom

    ! M x N fields, T_steps time steps
    integer :: M=0, N=0, T_steps=0
    ! set true to export an image array every step
    logical :: export_every_step = .False., print_every_step = .False.
    ! field_a and field_b will be iterated and set alternatingly
    logical, allocatable :: field_a(:,:), field_b(:,:), start_pattern(:,:)
    ! image array holds a 0/1 integer representation of a field
    integer, allocatable :: image_array(:,:)
    ! rule holds the update rule
    class(rule), allocatable :: rule
    ! data_dir is the directory where image and info files will be saved
    character(len=4) :: data_dir

    contains

    procedure, pass(this) :: general_init

    procedure, pass(this) :: setupField
    procedure, pass(this) :: random_seed_field
    procedure, pass(this) :: single_random_seed_field
    procedure, nopass :: compare_fields
    procedure, pass(this) :: reset_fields

    procedure, pass(this) :: export_image_array
    procedure, nopass :: print_logical_array
    procedure, pass(this) :: write_info_file
    procedure, pass(this) :: print_and_export_each_step

    procedure, pass(this) :: save_rule
    procedure, pass(this) :: open_rule

    procedure, pass(this) :: run
    procedure, pass(this) :: field_iteration
    procedure, pass(this) :: get_last_pattern
    procedure, pass(this) :: reset_to_last_start

end type cell_autom

! A general Moore automaton
type, extends(cell_autom) :: moore_autom

    contains

    procedure, pass(this) :: field_iteration => moore_iteration

end type

contains

! Constructor for moore_autom
function init_moore_autom(M, N, T_steps) result(inst)
    implicit none

    type(moore_autom) :: inst
    type(rule) :: moore_rule
    integer, intent(in) :: M, N, T_steps

    call inst%general_init(M, N, T_steps)

    call moore_rule%init_moore()
    allocate(inst%rule, source = moore_rule)

end function init_moore_autom
```

Comment: [I'm not currently with a compiler to test my suggestion.]  Your function result `inst` is allocatable, but isn't allocated before the point you try to allocate its component `inst%autom`.  That can't be good.  Does first allocating `inst` help?

Comment: Perhaps further to my previous comment: you could be using `class` far too much.  From the program it isn't obvious that you really want the polymorphism of `pf` (et al.) and so `type` would be sufficient.  When it comes to your function `setup` its result is polymorphic, but there's nothing obvious which says what dynamic type it should take.  If it were non-polymorphic and without the allocatable attribute the problem of determining and then allocating a dynamic type (or forgetting to) goes away.

Comment: I'm torn between writing an answer, and voting to close as a simple typo (not allocating a variable before using it).  Do you think it was just a "silly mistake" or is there a fundamental difficulty in the use of polymorphic function results?